# Azure B2C - Return email address entered for signing in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to return the email address the person used for authentication via an output claim.

I thought the claim would be "userPrincipalName", but that returns: "40568625-8d65-433a-9dc2-bafc1e969e8c@MYTENANT.onmicrosoft.com" in a "upn" claim, I need it to return the email address I used to login, which in this case is a gmail address.

When I view the User principal under accounts, it shows the gmail email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user signs up based on an email address, then the email address is stored in the **signInNames** property.

You could use [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api) to read this signInNames property. **Note:** signInNames is a collection of name objects. The email address is the name having type:emailAddress.

This url is used to [get a signed-in user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/signed-in-user-operations#get-the-signed-in-user--):

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version
```

For more details about email address storage, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview#email-address-storage).

Answer (score 0):

The correct attribute is signInNames.emailAddress.